# How to fix 'Chrome failed to start' error when running PyInstaller-generated binary with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create a binary file for my python application. I'm using `python 3.10.10` and compiling for Intel x86_64. In the app I need to use selenium for some scraping and I use [webdriver_manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) to handle the installation of the `chromedriver` binary. The function that handles the setup of the driver looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import os
import re
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def chrome_browser_setup():
    """
    Inizialize webdriver paramiters for a specific browser

    :return: Webdriver object with paramenters for the chosen browser.
    :rtype: selenium.webdriver
    """

    # Set driver of Chrome (requires version > 9.0)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # Specify verbosity level 0:info, 1:warnings, 2:error, 3:fatal
    options.add_argument('log-level=1')    
    # Disable popup
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

    return driver
```

I use [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) to create the binary (version 5.10.0). Now, if I run the app as a simple python scripts, it works with no issues, but when I run the executable created by pyinstaller I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "core/cpuCO2.py", line 37, in cpu_co2
  File "utils/cpu.py", line 61, in get_cpu_tdp
  File "utils/scraping.py", line 60, in scrape_tdp_intel
  File "utils/scraping.py", line 29, in chrome_browser_setup
  File "selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
  File "selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 106, in __init__
  File "selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 288, in __init__
  File "selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 381, in start_session
  File "selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
  File "selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x563cae404133 <unknown>
#1 0x563cae138966 <unknown>
#2 0x563cae16221a <unknown>
#3 0x563cae15e07b <unknown>
#4 0x563cae19d9ad <unknown>
#5 0x563cae19d18f <unknown>
#6 0x563cae1949a3 <unknown>
#7 0x563cae16946a <unknown>
#8 0x563cae16a55e <unknown>
#9 0x563cae3c3cae <unknown>
#10 0x563cae3c78fe <unknown>
#11 0x563cae3d0f20 <unknown>
#12 0x563cae3c8923 <unknown>
#13 0x563cae39bc0e <unknown>
#14 0x563cae3ebb08 <unknown>
#15 0x563cae3ebc97 <unknown>
#16 0x563cae3fc113 <unknown>
#17 0x7fc23c06dbb5 <unknown>

[137149] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

When I first looked for this error on internet most of the solutions involved manually downloading the chromedriver executable and set the path to it in the pyinstaller .spec file, which I did, but I kept getting the same error (I attempted with both relative and absolute pahts).

Then I tried adding the selenium hooks in the .spec files as suggested by some other solutions, like this:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

datas = []
datas += collect_data_files('selenium')
```

but the issue persisted.

I then tried to add these options for `ChromeDriver`:

```
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

but the issue persisted.

My Google Chrome version is 113.0.5672.92 and the chromedriver version I used when installed it manually is 113.0.5672.63. Could it be that these two versions are not compatible? How can I know if this is the case? The weirdest thing for me is that, as already mentioned, if launched as a script it works correctly, the only issue is the binary so I thought it couldn't be a problem of compatibility.

Comment: In my experience this is caused by a previous copy of chromedriver.exe that is still running in the background, possibly from a previous run of your application that didn't shutdown properly.  If that is the case then rebooting your pc or manually killing the process will fix the problem.